# How to implement facebook feed which shows the latest facebook wall post

Tags: social-network

I would like to display latest facebook wall post on my website. I found the [Facebook Pull](http://drupal.org/project/facebook_pull) module; but it doesn't work for me. I have add the appropriate app id and App Secret and nothing is showing up. Any ideas?

Do you know how  I can accomplish it? I never have a similar problem with a twitter_pull module which does the same but for the twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the facebook like box plugin? If you're just looking for a widget like capability on your site, this is the easiest and pushes the heavy lifting on to Facebook's servers without any more modules or extra PHP:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Play around with the options, you probably just want to show the stream. There are other options below to customize the output of this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the [Facebook Pull](http://drupal.org/project/facebook_pull) and it worked very well at my local. But when i pushed the code in the live website. The feed facebook didn't show up. I looked the log entries and find out there was the "Failed to fetch data from the Facebook Graph" error in the logs. I followed the http://drupal.org/node/1587598 patch and it worked well.